# mvn eclipse:eclipse does not add src in build path

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

Why `src` is not in the buildpath after I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create a eclipse project?

Should I add src to buildpath manually? I fear that this configuration will be lost after I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` the next time.

the project structure is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Could it be because it did not find any java files - you don't seem to have `src/main/java` folder?

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main goal of using maven is that helps to reduce the duplication of dependent software libraries (jars) required to build an application.So maven project structure is a little different to normal web application structure.If you worry to use maven,don't use maven project.You can add necessary libraries for your project manually.